# Installing AMD & Intel dual graphics

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have amd 7670m and intel hd 4000 series graphics on my laptop. 1st I installed Ubuntu 14.04 erasing windows 8. i have installed the AMD graphics but after i install the intel graphics then reboot i got this massage that my system is running on low graphics. Also i want to know that do i need to do anything else beside installing these 2 drivers for making them working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Intel graphics driver is built-in in Ubuntu, so you don't need to install an additional driver for the Intel graphics. It is also OK to have the proprietary AMD graphics driver and the built-in Intel graphics driver installed at the same time.

Whatever you did to install an unnecessary additional Intel graphics driver is what caused your low-graphics mode error message. To fix the problem, uninstall the unnecessary additional Intel graphics driver. If you can't remember the name of the graphics driver to uninstall it, you can find it by checking in the History tab in the Ubuntu Software Center, and if you installed it from the terminal you can find it by checking your terminal history using the `history` command.